# Função de jQuery deve ser executada somente no mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Acho que o título é auto-explicativo. Preciso que determinada função em jQuery "ative" apenas quando estou numa resolução menos de 1024px.

Comment: seria tipo uma media queries só que com o jquery?

Answer (score 7):

Você pode detectar o tamanho da tela e executar a função:

`screen.width` e `screen.height` respectivamente armazenam a largura e altura da tela.

```
if(screen.width < 1024){ 
   //executa a funcao para ativar
}
```

Outra forma que achei [aqui](http://wbruno.com.br/expressao-regular/detectando-browser-mobile-javascript/) utilizando javascript é assim:

A função retorna `true` caso o navegador utilizado for mobile e `false` caso contrário.

```js
function isMobile() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (userAgent.search(/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i) != -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Não me veio à cabeça na hora rs. Obrigado.